# How to assign different audio to different buttons after clicked event

Tags: javascript, foreach, click, this, addeventlistener

```
  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
```

```
var tekan = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

tekan.forEach(drum => {
drum.addEventListener("click", play);
})

function play() {
// const sound = ["crash.mp3", "kick.mp3", "snare.mp3", "tom1.mp3", "tom2.mp3", "tom3.mp3", "tom4.mp3"];

var audio = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
audio.play();  
};
```

When I click each button, it will only play the **crash.mp3** audio, how do I assign different audio like the one in **const sound** to each button?

I tried to use `this` keyword so that it changes the audio file source **(/crash.mp3)** in

```
var audio = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
```

according to the button clicked. I guess my knowledge of `this` keyword is still vague, or is there any way other than this? It would be great if I could only use `Javascript` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an event listener is triggered, the callback function receives the [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) that triggered it as an argument, with it you can determine which button was clicked. In your case you can use the element's `class` for that.

The element's class can be accessed using the `event.target.className` for the string with all of the classes or `event.target.classList` for a list containing a string for each class.

For your use case `classList[0]` contains the relevant information as the key label is the first class.

```js
const tekan = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

tekan.forEach(drum => {
  drum.addEventListener("click", play);
})

const drumSoundFiles = {
  "w": "crash.mp3", 
  "a": "kick.mp3", 
  "s": "snare.mp3",
  "d": "tom1.mp3", 
  "j": "tom2.mp3",
  "k": "tom3.mp3",
  "l": "tom4.mp3"
}

function play(event) {
  const pressedKey = event.target.classList[0]
  const soundFile = drumSoundFiles[pressedKey]

  const audio = new Audio(`sounds/${soundFile}`)
  audio.play()
};
```

Remember to map each key in the `drumSoundFiles` object to the correct sound.